# Database count query returns different result to equivalent select

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query with few joins, on running it shows 11 records.

When I run its count query (removed fields from `SELECT` part and put `COUNT(*)` there) it returns different number, 16.

Why just converting to count query returns different count than its original query?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste both queries here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have used `Select Distinct` when you are getting the number of rows 11 in result.

or

you are not using distinct in Count like `Count(Distinct fieldname)`, so `Count(*)` is giving all the record count.

Comment: I had used DISTINCT on both queries

Comment: you are not using distinct in Count like Count(Distinct fieldname), so Count(*) is giving all the record count.

Comment: Great!! So far I was using `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)`. Now I use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINC field_name)` and got the expected result! Please update the answer so I can select it :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your join query returns the same rows twice or more. You can see what i mean by executing select * from... query